# Mobile Paypal Payment Standard

Tags: paypal

I've developed e-shopping website and hypride mobile application. I have to integrate Paypal payment method in my applications. I decided to use Paypal Payment Standard Production of Paypal and implemented HTML Form Basics for PayPal Payments Standard on website and hypride mobile application. About website application work well, but hypride mobile application not responsive page. so can you help me to solve this problem ? 
Thank you for help me to answers.

Comment: Can you share *anything* that might be helpful to understanding your problem? (code, pictures, etc...)

Comment: <form id="form_cart" target="_self" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" style="display:none">
          <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
          <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
          <input type="hidden" name="business" value="7HD9KPMHAH2JW">
          <input type="hidden" name="handling_cart" value="0">
          <input type="hidden" name="discount_amount_cart" value="0">
      </form>

Comment: I implemented HTML Form Basic for Paypal Payment Standard on website, it work well, but when I implemented it on mobile web ( hypride app) it not show responsive page on mobile. This is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is my screenshot of my problem with mobile web
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqNb9.png

Comment: If can not make responsive in mobile web, Can you recommend me to implement other way for integrate paypal payment in mobile web ( hypride app ) ? Thank you for your answers.